# Mirror symmetry

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way to draw mirror/symmetric shapes in Inkscape? To clarify, I am asking about mirroring the shape while I'm drawing it, not to draw it and then mirror in.

I saw some videos on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfMdBir9H4) but I can't find the corresponding options on my version of Inkscape (v0.91)

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to make (and platform) [Krita](https://krita.org/) might interest you, it has very fluid and powerful symmetry functions. Its raster though not vector.

Comment: @Ryan It's not what I am looking for but it looks promising. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to this [Inkscape Forum](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=19017) entry the mirror path effect is included in a recent development release, but it is not (yet?) available from the current stable release.

We can however use a mirrored clone of an object with the same results:

[image]

Answer (score 19):

The Live Path Effect (LPE) "Mirror symmetry", incorporated in Inkscape 0.92, is perfect for this.
Short description here: [0.92 release notes, mirror symmetry](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.92#Mirror_Symmetry).
Demonstration video here: [Mirror Simmetry LPE for Inkscape](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1sj4AeU3Yo).

Simple usage:

- select the path you want to mirror
- select in the Path menu the item Path Effects
- in the Path Effects dialog, click on the + sign (add an effect) and select Mirror symmetry
- choose the right mode in the Path Effects dialog (eg. Free from reflection line)
- by then selecting the [node tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html) the reflection line appears, and its handles can be dragged

Answer (score 10):

## Clean symmetry cloning

---

*Here is how to clone and a tip for symmetric workflow. It is focused on a single path.*

*You can also group an object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and use the cloning process described below on that, allowing you to create new objects within that group that are then imitated by the clones as well.*

---

#### Creating clone that changes while working

With some starting **object selected**, go to **Edit->Clone->Create Tiled Clones** and in there the first tab is called symmetry. There is a whole selection available here but, what you want is the **reflection** one.
 Set **rows, columns** to ***1*** **x** ***4***. Why that is will be explained at the end.

The *first* clone appears *above* the original, the *second* to the *right*.
**If** you have ***already used*** this function before, the old values still exist and you *may* need to **reset** all relevant tabs.

> For ***working on the original*** after deselecting it (/selecting sth different), just select any clone and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> *id est*
>    **Select Original**.
>
> You can also delete the clone above your original. Which makes accidental deselection of the original less unlikely.

---

#### Finalizing and removing middle-node inaccuracy/gaps/duplicates in cloned paths.

When you are content with your design, you can remove gaps between two mirrored paths like that:

Selected the 3rd and 4th clone and unlink both by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then join the by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Now you can take care of those middle nodes which aren't quite in the middle:
In the **Node Edit Mode**, draw a selection frame around one middle node and its mirror node and from the options at the top, below your task bar, select join nodes. Repeat for each middle-node pair.

---

> By having cloned the tile four times you now have one final object of your design, and one working copy, ready for changes.
>
> Cloning the original again automatically removes any remaining unlinked clone, before creating the new ones. 
>   Just never join the original with a copy, otherwise you lose your working copy.